# How to manually create an array of 2D vectors in p5js and control it with a slider?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a function that takes separately the x and y values of a vector, say `vector = (a,b)`, in which case the x value would be `vector.x` (yielding a number `a`), and the y value `vector.y` (or `b`).

However, I have a bunch of such vectors, and they don't follow any specific pattern, so I want to enter them manually in an array or matrix, such as `array = [(a,b), (c,d), (e,f)]` and then control which one of the vectors is supplied to the function at each moment with a slider.

For instance, sliding to the right one step would activate the vector `(c,d)`, and both `c` and `d` would be fed into the function.

I know that an array can be entered as `[[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]]` and I can call `e` for instance as `array[2][0]`, but the function is set up to use the syntax `vector.x` and `vector.y`. I see how easy it would be to just change the function, but I am curious how I can manually create this vector manually, and then control it with a slider from `0` to `2` at integer increments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just map them:

```js
const array = [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f']]
const transformed = array.map(([x,y]) => ({x,y}))
console.log(transformed)
```

For the vector object:

```js
const array = [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f']]
const transformed = array.map(([x,y]) => (createVector(x, y)))
console.log(transformed)
```

Comment: I define it in function set up, but it doesn't recognize it when the function runs in function  draw.

Comment: @Patti how are we supposed to know what you are referring to... what you mean to recognize, probably you need `createVector(x, y)` instead of `({x,y})`

Comment: Can I insert createVector( ) in the code on your answer?

Comment: @Patti i've added another snipped that is using the createVector function